# git log -L cannot show the function history

Tags: php, git, function, logging, history

I use `git log -L :functionname:path` to show a function history. But it show nothing even when the functionname is in the file.

Here is the gitattributes config

```
$ cat ~/.gitattributes
*.php diff=php
```

With grep, it shows the funcitonname in the file file.

```
$ grep newSearchByNameSongList app/Http/Controllers/SongController.php
    public function newSearchByNameSongList(Request $request) {
```

But git log -L cannot match it

```
$ git log -L :newSearchByNameSongList:app/Http/Controllers/SongController.php
fatal: -L parameter 'newSearchByNameSongList' starting at line 1: no match
```

Here is the git version.

```
$ git version
git version 2.34.1.windows.1
```

Comment: `~/` is implying your current users home directory, the `.gitattributes` file should be stored inside your projects root directory - which for Laravel is the directory below `app`.